# Php Eclipse on windows azure using cloud storage in local testing

Tags: php, azure, cloud

I have been trying to access a queue that is on the cloud while running the role in dev fabric. To do that I followed the steps:

Project->Proprieties->Windows Azure->Data Storage and I selected the approrpiate fields and entered my credentials.

Then I do the following:

```
require_once 'Microsoft/WindowsAzure/Storage/Queue.php';

$storageClient = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue();
if( !($storageClient->queueExists('worktodo'))){
 $result=$storageClient->createQueue('worktodo');
 echo 'Created queue: ' . $result->Name."<br/>";
}else{
 echo 'worktodo queue exists'."<br/>";
}



$storageClient->putMessage('worktodo', $id.','.$name, 3600); // 3600 = time-to-live of the message, if omitted defaults to 7 days
echo($storageClient->getAccountName());
```

Long story short the queue are always created in DevStorage.... My Configuration settings:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="StorageAccountName" value="myaccoutnt/>
  <Setting name="StorageAccountKey" value="mykey"/>
  <Setting name="SqlAzureHost" value=""/>
  <Setting name="SqlAzureUserName" value=""/>
  <Setting name="SqlAzurePassword" value=""/>
  <Setting name="SqlAzureDatabase" value=""/>
  <Setting name="UseDataStorage" value="true"/>
  <Setting name="UseDevelopmentStorage" value="false"/>
  <Setting name="UseCloudStorage" value="true"/>
  <Setting name="UseSqlAzure" value="false"/>
  <Setting name="LogLevel" value="Error"/>
  <Setting name="ScheduledTransferPeriodInSeconds" value="30"/>
  <Setting name="WindowsAzureStorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=mykey"/>
  <Setting name="XDrives" value=""/>
  <Setting name="XDrivesLocalCache" value=""/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

Has anyone done this before ? Are my configuration settings correct ?

Thanks

Comment: At the very least, you're missing a question.

Comment: I think the question is "How can I make this work?"

Comment: @McWafflestix please see the added "?"

Comment: what you were missing wasn't just a question MARK, it was an actual question, such as "is there something missing from this configuration?" or "if anyone else has done this, how did they achieve success?"  Far from being pedantic, phrasing things in this way will really help you get an answer.

Comment: @McWafflestix changed, now that the questions are formulated as per your request I hope you can in return answer some of them. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
require_once 'Microsoft/WindowsAzure/Storage/Queue.php'; 

$storageClient = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue();
if (azure_getconfig("UseDevelopmentStorage") != "true") {
  $storageClient = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue(
    'queue.core.windows.net',
    azure_getconfig("StorageAccountName"),
    azure_getconfig("StorageAccountKey")
  );
} 

if (!($storageClient->queueExists('worktodo'))) { 
  $result = $storageClient->createQueue('worktodo'); 
  echo 'Created queue: ' . $result->Name . "<br/>"; 
} else { 
  echo 'worktodo queue exists' . "<br/>"; 
} 


$storageClient->putMessage('worktodo', $id.','.$name, 3600); // 3600 = time-to-live of the message, if omitted defaults to 7 days 
echo($storageClient->getAccountName());
```

Long story short: you should always pass the actual connection details when connecting to Windows Azure storage.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the value of 
 in ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file in the project? It should be set to "false"

Comment: please see the edit to my post for the Configuration Setting, thanks !